# Prototyped variable is undefined

Tags: javascript

at college I am required to create a javascript game with a Model View Controller style coding. I'm trying to code the player input but my controller can't access the `movesRight` variable for some reason. Can anybody help me?

INPUT:

```
GOBLINS.View.prototype.input = function() {

    var self = this;
    this.movesRight = false;

    window.addEventListener('keydown', keyDown, true);

    function keyDown(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 39){
            self.movesRight = true;
            console.log(self.movesRight);
        };
    };
};
```

MOVEMENT:

```
GOBLINS.View.prototype.movement = function(character){
            character.xpos++;
    };
```

CONTROLLER:

```
GOBLINS.Controller.prototype.mainLoop = function() {
    var self = this;   

    this.M.getData(function(data){
        self.V.update(data);
    });

    if(this.V.input.movesRight == true){
        this.V.movement(this.M.images[0]);
    };
```

Comment: from here the `self.movesRight` looks ok, are you sure that's the issue? put a break point in the key down event and check what `self` is

Comment: Is it on purpose that in the controller you then use this and not self? (last if shown)

Comment: MVC confuses me a lot. I guess I used this in the controller because 'this' references back to the controller so I can acces the model and view.

Comment: There is no actual error, the script just doesn't work. But when I console.log movesRight from the mainLoop with console.log(this.V.input.movesRight); it returns "undefined" .

Comment: Two questions: 1. Is `this.V` an instance of `GOBLINS.View.prototype`? 2. If the answer to one is positive, the why are you trying to get `this.V.input.movesRight` instead of `this.V.movesRight`?

Comment: Because I put this.movesRight within GOBLINS.View.prototype.input

Comment: `this` in the context of the `.prototype` property usually refers to the instance (i.e. `this.V` in the Controller)  and not to a part of the `.prototype` Object itself (unless you access it via `GOBLINS.View.prototype.input()`, but that seems unlikely in your case).